# Move to rootViewController once data has been fetched

Tags: ios, segue, completionhandler

I am a newbie in iOS - Objective C and I am trying to implement a login functionality. The diagram of my Storyboard looks like this:

[image]

So when someone clicks on the Account option it goes into the Profile view Controller and in the `viewWillAppear` method checks whether there are any user data. If not, it performs a segue to the Log In view controller.

When the user clicks on the Log In button and the api call is successful I want to go back to the Profile view controller. The thing is, although I do manage to get the data back it won't let me go back to the Profile view controller.

```
   // code that creates the request and adds POST data and headers is not added to keep code sample to minimum


    NSURLSessionConfiguration *configuration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
    NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:configuration delegate:nil delegateQueue:nil];

    // execute data task

    NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSDictionary *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        if (responseData != nil) {
            if ([[responseData valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
                //delegate to pass the user data to Profile view controller
                [self.delegate passUserDetails:[responseData objectForKey:@"user"]];
                [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];

            } else if ([[responseData valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ERROR"]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [responseData valueForKey:@"error"]);
            }
         } else {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong, please try again");
         }

     }];

     [dataTask resume];
```

The issue I get is on my console is

`This application is modifying the autolayout engine from a background thread, which can lead to engine corruption and weird crashes.`

I 've read in previous posts that I can use `dispatch_async` as a possible solution to the problem but I don't understand where exactly. If that's correct do I need to use it as a wrapper for my `completionHandler`? Is there something I 'm doing wrong (possibly)? Is there any other way to implement what I have in mind?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The completionHandler on a `NSURLSession dataTaskWithRequest...` call is run on a background thread. Most UIKit calls need to be made from the main thread.

Enclose those calls in:

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
// insert your code here 
});
```

within your completionHandler.

In your case:

```
NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData * _Nullable data, NSURLResponse * _Nullable response, NSError * _Nullable error) {

        NSDictionary *responseData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:0 error:nil];
        if (responseData != nil) {
            if ([[responseData valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"OK"]) {
                //delegate to pass the user data to Profile view controller
                [self.delegate passUserDetails:[responseData objectForKey:@"user"]];
                dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                    [self.navigationController popToRootViewControllerAnimated:YES];
                };

            } else if ([[responseData valueForKey:@"status"] isEqualToString:@"ERROR"]) {
                NSLog(@"%@", [responseData valueForKey:@"error"]);
            }
         } else {
            NSLog(@"Something went wrong, please try again");
         }

     }];
```

If `passUserDetails` makes any calls that update the UI, you'll need to include it as well.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification. I 've wrapped the `NSURLSessionDataTask *dataTask` inside the `dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{});` but unfortunately I still get the same error. Any ideas?

Comment: No, you need to wrap the UI-related code inside the `dispatch_async` call inside the completionHandler.

Comment: Updated answer to be more explicit.

Comment: That's great! Worked like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

I think you should simply present the login view controller modally and after login successful you can just dismiss the login view controller ..... As modal presentation is used for grabbibg short dat from user .so presenting login controller modally will best pratice.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to go back to root view controller then you might used the code below... I am answering from my phone so type the sentence Ho avoid naming conventions error.
[ self.navigationController popTorootviewController];